# Disable button when current time equal to a specific value

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is there a way to disable a button when the current time is equal to a specific value?

Take a look at this page:
[Sample Page](http://www.777auction.ca/online/index.php?module=listings&controller=listing&action=details&id=30768)

I'd like to disable the "Submit Bid" button when the countdown is done (the end time can be returned through $listing['end_time']. Is there a script that I can add to the page that would do that?

This is my code for the button:

```
<button name="bid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Bid</button>
```

I tried this method but it didn't seem to work:

```
<script>
var sec = <?php echo (time() - $listing[end_time])?>;
var bid = document.getElementById('bid');
window.onload = countDown;

function countDown() {
  if (sec <= 0) {
    $("#bid").addClass("disabled");
    return;
  }
  sec -= 1;
  window.setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: you have the answer in the source code of the page you've linked already! just look at line 515.

Comment: off topic: if this part of the page is sensitive, just make sure any form processing is also disabled on the PHP script at that specific time, anyone would just setup the form in the inspect element and add another button themselves and just submit it.

Comment: That was part of my trials... I tested it but it didn't work

Comment: Then post what you've tried and what has failed (error messages?) and we'll help!

Comment: I edited my original message with the code I tried. I didn't get any errors, just nothing happened to the button.

Comment: NOTE: the disabled property can be altered by the client! on submit, you should either check it again using a serverside javascript or php function

Answer (score 0):

You Can Simply use an if else like this

```
<?php if(listing['end_time']== $endedtime){ ?>
<button name="bid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Submit Bid</button><?php }
else{ ?>
<button name="bid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit Bid</button><?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this will only disable the button the first time the user views the page. I want to disable the button while the user is viewing the page the moment the countdown is complete.

Comment: also, make it greater then, otherwise it'll fail if only a second too late.